# Azure permission missing Microsoft.Web/sites/host/properties/read

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-roles

I am trying to add the following permission to an Azure role due to an error I am seeing in the logs - *Microsoft.Web/sites/host/properties/read*. However, I cant find this permission to apply when I edit the role definition. Any idea?

Comment: That permission `_Microsoft.web/sites/host/properties/read_` is not found. After `_Microsoft.web/sites/host/_` - `listkeys/action`, `sync/action`, `listsyncstatus/action`, `functionkeys/write`, `functionkeys/delete`, `systemkeys/write` and `systemkeys/delete` are available. Please check this [RBAC Resource provider operations for Microsoft.Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftweb).

Comment: As Hari commented, this permission does not exist. Maybe this permission would be sufficient Microsoft.Web/sites/Read ?

Comment: I totally agree that this permission does not exist. Yet that was what was explicitly being listed in the the error message. Hence the question. However, I added the */read permission and that fixed the issue. Although as suggested, the Microsoft.Web/sites/Read could also have been sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad [JakeUT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2686261/jakeut) that you resolved the issue using the `*/read` permission.

As per this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftweb)), hat permission `_Microsoft.web/sites/host/properties/read_` is not found. After `_Microsoft.web/sites/host/_` - `listkeys/action`, `sync/action`, `listsyncstatus/action`, `functionkeys/write`, `functionkeys/delete`, `systemkeys/write` and `systemkeys/delete` are available.

And from this [GitHub Article](https://github.com/Azure/portaldocs/blob/main/portal-sdk/generated/portalfx-permissions.md#at-a-glance), it is said that:

> If the resource type is dynamic and the required permission is standard across all supported resource types (e.g. read, write), you can use relative permissions by replacing the resource type with "." or "{resourceType}". For instance, if checking read access on a website, you can check for "**./read**", which will be evaluated as "**`Microsoft.Web/sites/read`**". For a website deployment slot, this would be evaluated as "`Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/read`".